# NSFilehandle Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I am trying to get the information returned from the command line into my program as a string.
This is my code, i have tried a few other variations with no luck.

```
    let MyTask : NSTask = NSTask()
    MyTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/cal"
    MyTask.arguments = ["04","2014"]
    MyTask.launch()
    MyTask.waitUntilExit()
    var TheHandle = MyTask.standardOutput as  NSFileHandle
    println(TheHandle)
    var Data = TheHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
    var DataAsString = NSString(data: Data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(DataAsString)
```

The output

```
     April 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30

<_NSStdIOFileHandle: 0x6180000e4f80>
2014-11-14 23:22:40.014 Command Reader[6631:118648] *** -[_NSStdIOFileHandle     readDataOfLength:]: Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task's standard output must be *set* to a file handle that the process can write to.
For communication between a parent process and a child process, this is usually done
with a *pipe*. The child process writes to the writing end of the pipe, and the
parent process reads from the reading end:

```
let myTask  = NSTask()

myTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/cal"
myTask.arguments = ["04","2014"]

let pipe = NSPipe()
myTask.standardOutput = pipe

myTask.launch()
myTask.waitUntilExit()

let theHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
let data = theHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
if let dataAsString = NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println(dataAsString)
} else {
    println("could not convert output to string")
}
```

*Remarks:*

- `myTask.standardOutput` is set to the pipe itself. This causes the process to
  write to `pipe.fileHandleForWriting`, and close that file descriptor when finished.
  If the file descriptor were not closed then `theHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()`
  in the parent process would wait indefinitely.
- I have used variables starting with lower-case letters, which is the usual convention in Swift.

If you want the process output written to a file, then you can create the file,
open it as a file handle and pass that handle to `myTask.standardOutput`:

```
let myTask  = NSTask()
myTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/cal"
myTask.arguments = ["04","2014"]

let path = "/path/to/output.txt" // where the output should be written ...
if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)) {
    println("could not create file")
} else if let theHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: path) {
    myTask.standardOutput = theHandle

    myTask.launch()
    myTask.waitUntilExit()
    theHandle.closeFile()
} else {
    println("could not open file")
}
```

Comment: Sweet, Thanks works perfectly. A side question though, if i used setStandardOutput to a nsfilehandle does the system actually create a file i can look at in nano or vim or even in finder that contains the input and output of my NSTask?

Comment: @nsij22: Yes you can. I will update the answer later.

Comment: Sweet excitedly waiting for your update lol, it would be amazing if i you could post some links or information about standardized file paths to get there or filehandles and their links to actual file paths :-D